# Convert 3D models from g3db to Collada

Tags: 3d, three.js, libgdx, collada

Is there any way that I could convert a 3D model under the `g3db` format to the `Collada` format?

A bit more context: I have a three.js website that I use to show some `Collada` models. I recently received 3D models from a client under the `g3db` format, and I would like to show them in this website that uses three.js. I want to avoid bothering my client again and telling him to send me files under another format.

Comment: I don't think anyone has written one. But you can look up the fbx-conv source code in the Libgdx Github project to see how the format works so you can write a converter.

Comment: I am sure calling your client for another format is much easier than writing your own converter.

Comment: If they are single-node, non-animated meshes, it would be fairly easy to use Libgdx as a library to load the mesh, and then write it to Wavefront format. Otherwise, yes, you are looking at many hours to write a working converter.